# Comment on Post gets a page not found error, but still post the comment

Tags: django

I have a comment section for my post form. This is all in my post details. When a comment is posted you get a page not found error: http://localhost:8000/post/15/. post fifteen does not exist. Each comment will add to the post but the post in the error increments by one each time.

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vc = self.object.view_count
        self.object.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.view_count = vc + 1
        initial_comment_data = {
            'post': self.get_object(),
        }
        data['comment_form'] = CommentModelForm(initial=initial_comment_data)
        return data

class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentModelForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)#title of a post
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #if a user is deleted all of their post will be as well
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_files = models.FileField(null = True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('forum.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I want the comment to go into the correct post like it does, but with out the page not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Comment.get_absolute_url` method is passing in the `pk` of the `comment` instead of the `post`.

Try this instead:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # notice I use self.post.pk here instead of self.pk
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})
```

I think it'd be best practice for the `Comment.get_absolute_url` to return the URL of the comment.

On your `CreateView` you can define a `get_success_url` [1] that instead redirects to the `Post`.

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.post.get_absolute_url()
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url